# lost dimension in numpy array acquired from a dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a dataframe (you may see the image of the dataframe from the provided link).

```
df.shape, type(girdi), type(girdi.iloc[0, 0])
>>>(10292, 5), pandas.core.frame.DataFrame, numpy.ndarray)
```

Each value in this dataframe is a NumPy array with 55 data points in it (55, ).

```
df.iloc[0,0]
>>>array([64.75, 65.62, 64.21, 64.62, 63.94, 62.63, 62.24, 62.65, 62.47,
       63.17, 63.46, 63.75, 65.41, 65.35, 65.68, 65.97, 66.6 , 66.45,
       66.11, 65.48, 64.22, 63.54, 62.81, 63.58, 62.46, 61.23, 62.26,
       61.13, 61.68, 61.36, 61.93, 61.48, 61.92, 62.43, 63.37, 62.59,
       63.33, 63.52, 63.23, 62.52, 63.03, 63.61, 63.83, 63.7 , 63.94,
       65.14, 66.  , 66.65, 65.87, 64.93, 65.84, 64.75, 65.5 , 65.7 ,
       66.83])
```

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv0Pp.png)

When I convert the whole dataframe to a NumPy array NumPy does not recognize the 3rd dimension.

```
X = np.array(df)
X.shape
>>>(10292, 5)

X.shape, type(X)
>>>((10292, 5), numpy.ndarray)

X[0].shape, type(X[0])
>>>((5,), numpy.ndarray)

X[0, 0].shape, type(X[0, 0])
>>>((55,), numpy.ndarray)
```

I expect (and desire) to get:

```
X.shape, X[0, 0, 0]
>>>(10292, 5, 55), 64.75
```

To access the data, using `X[0][0][0]` or `X[0, 0] [0]` helps, though it does not help *my needs*. I want to access the data with `X[0, 0, 0]`.

I tried using `np.vstack` or `np.expand_dims`, though I was unsuccessful. How may I turn the data to `(10292, 5, 55)` dimensions?

Thank you,
Evrim

Comment: There isn't a third dimension in your dataframe.  Dataframes are always 2d.  This frame has object dtype, where each of the cell values is a numpy array.  But with object dtype those cells don't have to be arrays, nor do they all have to be the same shape.  They could be numbers, strings, `None`, or who-know-what.  And `X` reflects that generality!

Comment: For one column, a Series, the resulting array will be 1d, (10292,) shape,and `vstack` (or `stack`) will work to make a (10292,55) array.   Try this instead: `np.array(X.tolist())`.

Comment: Thank you, hpaulj. I was hoping to find a simple solution as yours. This works like a charm. Kudos

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to create a new array with the desired dimensions and traverse your matrix of arrays (X)

```py
result = np.zeros(X.shape + X[0, 0].shape)
for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    for j in range(X.shape[1]):
        result[i, j] = X[i, j]
```

Comment: Thank you, Gabriel, I was just writing something very similar to this. This works great.
Cheers